Render engine question
When I render PNG sequence from Blender and make it video Render in Adobe After Effectd, color is not what I see in Blender or After effect Screen.
Final video color is a little bit different.  Does anyone know what should I do to match with screen color and Render color?

You could render in openexr which render in linear color and then change the color space in after effect to get the desired color space (like sRGB)

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
